# Ant design - How to adjust table column width by dragging?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, antd

Is there any way to let users to adjust column width of [Ant Design Table](https://ant.design/components/table/) by drag and drop?

I found some examples that about is for column sorting, but not for column resizing.

Please help, thanks!

---

UPDATED @ 2018-11-13

There is an official example of resizing table column now:

https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-resizable-column

Comment: there is no inbuilt feature, you can take a look at drag-sorting feature and implement this -https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-drag-sorting

Comment: @AseemGautam Thanks for your advice. Actually I am trying to implement the function based on this example now. However I still can't figure out the solution yet.

Comment: I think you can make use of `onHeaderCell` and https://codepen.io/graham_saunders/pen/vrDxf example to make it work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have made a working sample - its far from perfect and needs a lot of optimization. Basically you need to use the `onHeaderCell` and capture `onMouseDown`, `onMouseUp` and `onMouseMove`.

`onMouseMove` we call `setState` and basically trigger a re-render with the new column width.

https://codesandbox.io/s/j2zw9nn5w9
[image: Antd adjust table column width by dragging]

```
onHeaderCell: column => {
  let colw = this.state.columnWidth;
  return {
    onMouseDown: e => {
      this.mouseDownX = e.clientX;
      this.beginDrag = true;
    },
    onMouseUp: () => {
      this.beginDrag = false;
    },
    onMouseMove: e => {
      if(this.beginDrag === true) {
        this.updateColumnWidth(colw + 
        Math.round((e.clientX - this.mouseDownX)*.05));
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aseem Gautam ! Although https://codesandbox.io/s/j2zw9nn5w9  is not work as the gif, it really helps me to implement the feature! :)

Comment: oops, sorry, it seems code did not get saved. I have just updated again, sandbox works fine now. It behaves as in the gif.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate that! :)

Comment: For me, the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/j2zw9nn5w9 is still not working. It's giving errors.

Comment: Just delete the `<Icon type="down" />` on the line 87

Answer (score 1):

**Working version, without using react-resizable**

```
interface TableContextProps {
    columns: any[];
    setColumns: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any[]>>;
}

const TableContext = createContext<TableContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const GridWrapper = (props: IProps) => {
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState<any[]>(props.columns);

    return (
        <TableContext.Provider value={{ columns, setColumns }}>
            <TableWrapper {...props} />
        </TableContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const TableWrapper = (wrapperProps) => {
    const { columns, setColumns } = useContext(TableContext)!;

    const handleResize = (columnIndex: number, width: number) => {
        setColumns((prevColumns) => {
            const newColumns = [...prevColumns];
            newColumns[columnIndex] = {
                ...newColumns[columnIndex],
                width,
            };
            return newColumns;
        });
    };

    const renderResizableTitle = (column: any, columnIndex: number) => {
        return (
            <div className="resizable-title" style={{ width: column.width }}>
                {column.title}
                <div
                    className="resizable-handle"
                    onMouseDown={(e) => handleMouseDown(e, columnIndex)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    };

    let startX = 0;
    let startWidth = 0;
    let resizingColumnIndex: number | null = null;

    const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, columnIndex: number) => {
        startX = e.pageX;
        startWidth = columns[columnIndex].width;
        resizingColumnIndex = columnIndex;

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    };

    const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        if (resizingColumnIndex !== null) {
            const offsetX = e.pageX - startX;
            const newWidth = startWidth + offsetX;
            if (newWidth > 0) {
                handleResize(resizingColumnIndex, newWidth);
            }
        }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        resizingColumnIndex = null!;
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    };

    return (
        <div className={`grid___wrapperContainer ${wrapperProps.cssClass}`}>
            <Table
                columns={columns.map((column, index) => {
                    debugger
                    return ({
                        ...column,
                        title: renderResizableTitle(column, index),
                    })
                })}
                dataSource={wrapperProps.rows}
                onChange={wrapperProps.onChange}
                pagination={false}
                bordered={true}
                size={'small'}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).